# How to flush xml file in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, xml, response

I want to return a xml file to a client, and THEN perform my logic.
I try to use Response.Flush(), but it doesn't work correctly for me.

My code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string arg1= this.Request["arg1"];
string arg2= this.Request["arg2"];
string arg3= this.Request["arg3"];

var doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode responseNode = doc.CreateElement("response");
doc.AppendChild(responseNode);

var messageNode = responseNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("message"));
messageNode.InnerText = "Your request is being processed";

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"; 
Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
doc.Save(Response.Output);
Response.Flush(); // I want to display xml in this moment but it doesn't work

LogicManager manager = new LogicManager();
manager.DoSth(arg1, arg2, arg3);

Response.End();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to use `ashx` to handle this kind of requests. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Response.End();

Generally, it is a bad idea to be using Response.End() in your code.

[From the source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.end%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): This method is provided only for compatibility with ASP—that is, for compatibility with COM-based Web-programming technology that preceded ASP.NET. If you want to jump ahead to the EndRequest event and send a response to the client, it is usually preferable to call CompleteRequest instead.

Given this info, instead of this:

```
Response.Flush(); // I want to display xml in this moment but it doesn't work

LogicManager manager = new LogicManager();
manager.DoSth(arg1, arg2, arg3);

Response.End();
```

do this:

```
Response.Flush(); // I want to display xml in this moment but it doesn't work
Response.CompleteRequest();

LogicManager manager = new LogicManager();
manager.DoSth(arg1, arg2, arg3);
// here you might want to make sure that no other page handlers are executed
```